# Flutter realtime Firebase CRUD notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Here's the thing. I'm still learning Flutter integration with Realtime Firebase. I'm able to retrieve data from database without any problem. However how do i get my app to notify the operation is a success by using a toast? The following code is not working to display toast when the operation is not success.

```
  void getData() {
    String devid = _idcontroller.text;
    firebaseref.child(devid).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      String msj = '${snapshot.value['message']}';
      if (msj.length >1){
        _msjcontroller.text = msj;
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Success!!!",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      }else{
         Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Message not found!!!",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      }

    });
  }
```

Comment: What is `msg` equal to?

Comment: msj just some string value retrieved from my firebase. Under devid table there is a message field that contain this string.

Comment: check for errors in the log, also how are u using `getData`?

Comment: no error unfortunately. i got the message correctly from firebase..but stuck on notification if no message retrieve. i can make it to work easily with http request response  but flutter n firebase is new to me and the way it responded I'm still working on it.. just for user can get notification if no data receive.

Comment: how are u calling getData?

Comment: from button widget onpress. nothing fancy just simple method call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206149/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-hanis).

Answer (score 0):

Found it...Not the best solution..but it works..

```
void getData() {
    String devid = _idcontroller.text;
    firebaseref.child(devid).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.value);
      if (snapshot.value == null){
        print("Hello");
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "No Data!!!",
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      }else{
        String msj = '${snapshot.value['message']}';
        _msjcontroller.text = msj;
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "Success",
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,);
      }

    });
  }
```